# Returning Task<bool> in F#, what is the syntax?

Tags: f#

I need to write a function that will return a Task in F#.

The closest I came to is:

```
        let Test : Async<bool> =
            async {
                printfn "3"
                true
            }
```

but.. that doesn't work; the compiler says I'm giving an Async instead of an Async.

Am I correct to understand that there is no Task object and the return type should be defined as Async?

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Use `return true`.

Comment: it works; why is return needed instead of just the value, like in a regular let expression?

Comment: async computation expressions require a return

Comment: I think this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions . You may also take a look here: http://tryjoinads.org/docs/computations/monads.html

Comment: I had tried to read about monads earlier today, but I didn't get it. I'll try that link to see if it's more clear :) thanks!

Comment: so, if I understand, the operators with the '!' are essentially about returning / passing around a Task<T> and not T; is that correct?

Comment: Yes. A complete reference for how an async computation expression is translated to the explicit builder syntax is given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions#creating-a-new-type-of-computation-expression) (Scroll down a bit to the section that lists each expression and its translation).

Comment: This can then be combined with the [definition of AsyncBuilder](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/c18e1780b3f3f345364cb1ad8e510ea9f4590d3a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L1061), to get a complete understanding of what is happening, with the syntactic sugar removed.

Comment: one thing I don't get though: with let a = async { let! t = myC#MethodReturningATask() return t } I should have 'a' of type 'Task', isn't it? since the let! would return the Task and not the result of it. But this doesn't seem to work like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# doesn't have a computation expression for the `Task` construct built-in by default.

However if you want to use it, you can (thanks to `rspeele`). You'll have to add this as a nuget package: https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs

Then you can use it like this:

```ml
open FSharp.Control.Tasks.V2

let taskMethod : Task<bool> = 
    task {
        printfn "3"
        return true
    }
```

If you want to stick with the built-in `Async` approach you can do something like this:

```ml
open System.Threading.Tasks

let asyncMethod : Async<bool> = 
    async {
        printfn "bob"
        return true
    }

let taskMethod : Task<bool> = 
    asyncMethod |> Async.StartAsTask
```